# React native webview with login facebook always redirect in another url in release mode (android only)

Tags: react-native, facebook-login, react-native-webview

i've a webview with these line of code:

```
<WebView
            userAgent={`Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.1.0; Android SDK built for x86 Build/OSM1.180201.021; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/61.0.3163.98 Mobile Safari/537.36`}
            source={{
              uri: `https://www.facebook.com/v8.0/dialog/oauth?client_id=xxx&redirect_uri=yyyy`,
            }}
            incognito={true}
            onNavigationStateChange={(state) => {
              let url = state.url;
              console.log(url);
              var regex = /[?&]([^=#]+)=([^&#]*)/g,
                params = {},
                match;
              while ((match = regex.exec(url))) {
                params[match[1]] = match[2];
              }
              if (params.code) {
                setLoading(true);
                setModalVisible(false);
                processFbcode(params.code);
              }
              if (params.error) {
                setLoading(false);
                setModalVisible(false);
              }
            }}
            startInLoadingState={true}
            renderLoading={() => (
              <ActivityIndicator
                style={{
                  position: 'absolute',
                  left: 0,
                  right: 0,
                  top: 0,
                  bottom: 0,
                  alignItems: 'center',
                  justifyContent: 'center',
                  backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)',
                }}
                size="large"
                color="#0000ff"
              />
            )}
            style={{marginBottom: '10%'}}
          />
```

in debug mode, i run that code without any error, the console log shows me:

`about:blank` => `https://www.facebook.com/v8.0/dialog/oauth?client_id=xxx&redirect_uri=yyyy`=> other url for authenticating

but in release mode, with the same code above and the same url inside webview (source={{...}}), i see that in `adb logcat`:

```
https://m.facebook.com/login.php?skip_api_login=1&api_key=xxx&kid_directed_site=0&app_id=zzz&signed_next=1&next=(myUrlAbove)&cancel_url=(otherURL)%26error_code%3D200%26error_description%3DPermissions%2Berror%26error_reason%3Duser_denied%23_%3D_&display=touch&locale=vi_VN&pl_dbl=0&refsrc=https%3A%2F%2Fm.facebook.com%2Fv8.0%2Fdialog%2Foauth&_rdr
```

why react native webview in 2 mode load 2 different url? (with the same code for handling and same init url provided inside webview source)?

P/s: i've defined key hash on my facebook developer app before calling `react-native run-android --variant=release`

My react-native version: 0.63.4

My react-native-webview version: 11.3.1 (newest)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?

Comment: @AjayMakwana sadly i had to use other way to get it working. I used fbsdk and not webview anymore

Comment: Thank you for your response, I did the same.